# Getting individual data from node-red Object?

Tags: javascript, object, node-red

I am working with node-red where i am returning an object from a function like below...

```
{task1:"14124.44",task2:"23123.22",task3:"22323.22",_msgid:"33erewfddsfds"}
```

From the result above i want to get different value separately like e.g. "task1".
I tried different things in another function block
e.g. msg.payload[0] or msg.payload['task1'] but not succeeded.

Comment: Have you tried msg.task1 or msg['task1']?

Comment: Can you show where in your code you are trying to access `task1` and from which variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the sample you have provided has a `_msgid` field this looks like the data is in the root of the msg object, so you don't want to be looking in the `msg.payload`

So assuming you are in the function node you want to access the field names directly:

```
var task1 = msg.task1
var task2 = msg.task2
```

The `[number]` notation is for accessing array entries, not named fields, which can be accessed with `['field name']`.